# Java Permission for Jackson on Domino XPage

Tags: java, security, jackson

Using Codehaus Jackson on a Domino Server within an XPages produces the following stack trace

```
[07715:00011-2293234576] 04/02/2013 10:28:12 AM  HTTP JVM: java.lang.SecurityException: not allowed to access members in class class java.util.ArrayList
[07715:00011-2293234576] 04/02/2013 10:28:12 AM  HTTP JVM:  at java.lang.Throwable.<init>(Throwable.java:67)
[07715:00011-2293234576] 04/02/2013 10:28:12 AM  HTTP JVM:  at lotus.notes.AgentSecurityManager.checkMemberAccess(Unknown Source)
[07715:00011-2293234576] 04/02/2013 10:28:12 AM  HTTP JVM:  at java.lang.Class.checkMemberAccess(Class.java:112)
[07715:00011-2293234576] 04/02/2013 10:28:12 AM  HTTP JVM:  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:675)
[07715:00011-2293234576] 04/02/2013 10:28:12 AM  HTTP JVM:  at org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.AnnotatedClass._addMemberMethods(AnnotatedClass.java:620)
[07715:00011-2293234576] 04/02/2013 10:28:12 AM  HTTP JVM:  at org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.AnnotatedClass.resolveMemberMethods(AnnotatedClass.java:413)
[07715:00011-2293234576] 04/02/2013 10:28:12 AM  HTTP JVM:  at org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.classWithCreators(BasicClassIntrospector.java:185)
[07715:00011-2293234576] 04/02/2013 10:28:12 AM  HTTP JVM:  at org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.collectProperties(BasicClassIntrospector.java:157)
[07715:00011-2293234576] 04/02/2013 10:28:12 AM  HTTP JVM:  at org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.forSerialization(BasicClassIntrospector.java:96)
[07715:00011-2293234576] 04/02/2013 10:28:12 AM  HTTP JVM:  at org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.forSerialization(BasicClassIntrospector.java:16)
[07715:00011-2293234576] 04/02/2013 10:28:12 AM  HTTP JVM:  at org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig.introspect(SerializationConfig.java:973)
```

In the java.policy I tried this settings:

```
// Jackson (JSON)
permission java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission "suppressAccessChecks";
// permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessDeclaredMembers";
// permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessClassInPackage.java.util.ArrayList";
permission java.security.AllPermission;
```

The first permission has nothing to do with the current problem.
I tried to solve it with the second and third setting, but it doesn't work.

Only the last setting helps, but that's way to much...
Any better solutions?

Comment: All involving classes/jars in the call stack needs to have the correct permissions, not only the last caller. You're not showing the complete policy section and stack trace, so it's hard to say if that is the issue. It would be helpful if you could add some more information.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/iP3YNchM

Comment: http://pastebin.com/XbHSRnTy

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Domino XPages, but I assume it follows the standard Java security scheme, so here's a few thoughts/ideas:

Do not put your application specific security configuration in the "global" space. Instead, find the correct codebase and add it to it's own codepase section in the java.policy file:

```
grant codeBase "myCodeBase" {
    // Security configuration here, e.g.
    // permission java.security.AllPermission;
    // If you end up using AllPermissions, at least it only applies to your app
};
```

Figure out what your "codeBase" is and insert it in place of "myCodeBase".

For specific permissions needed for different types of access, you can check the document [Permissions in Java™ SE 7 Development Kit (JDK)](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html). In your stacktrace it seems like it's the call `getDeclaredMethods` that is the cause of the problem. In the document mentioned, the required permissions are described:

> java.lang.Class
>
> > public Class[] getDeclaredClasses()
> >     public Field[] getDeclaredFields()
> >
> > public Method[] getDeclaredMethods()
> >
> > public Constructor[] getDeclaredConstructors()
> >
> > public Field getDeclaredField(String name)
> >
> > public Method getDeclaredMethod(...)
> >
> > public Constructor getDeclaredConstructor(...)

needs permissions

> Default checkMemberAccess does not require any permissions if "this" class's classloader is the same as that of the caller. Otherwise, it requires java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessDeclaredMembers". If this class is in a package, java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessClassInPackage.{pkgName}" is also required.

So your commented entries in the policy files seems correct. If you uncomment those lines, it should solve this particular security exception, but you might encounter new ones.

**Edit:** You say cou can't specify a codebase for your application, but you should at least be able to specify a codebase pointing to your specific jar file, like this:

```
grant codeBase "file://file_url_to_jar" { }
```

It might not solve your problem, but could get you a step further.

**Edit:**

If all else fails, and it still does not work, you can turn on java security debugging. It'll produce a lot of output, but it can be helpful to track down security errors. Enable it by adding `-Djava.security.debug=all` to the JVM startup options.

**Edit:**

For this particular permission (`accessDeclaredMembers`), the problem could possibly be fixed by adding the jackson jar to the lib/ext folder of the JVM, as this would make the classes be loaded with the same classloader as the JRE classes, and the `accessDeclaredMembers` check is skipped.

Comment: No, the commented lines don't solve this particular security exception, that's why I asked the question here. I read the Java Permission documentation. There I found the permissions, that I tried, but as I wrote, They don't work... Regarding the grant block, I develop Java on Domino for more then 10 years, as fare as I know there is no other way then to use the global grant block.

Comment: Yes, I know that you mentioned that you had tried those lines. But do you get the exact same exception? Or do you get a different stacktrace? Also, I found this resource, which indicates that it should be possible to specific grant block: http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-8JYAT5

I have been through setting up security for an application recently, and I know by experience how cumbersome it is to get all the correct permissions set up. You fix one, and then the next one hits you. So it's easy to overlook two different security exceptions that look almost the same.

Comment: No, exact the same exception.

Comment: I have edited the answer with one more suggestion about codebase. Also, do you have more stack traces than this one? SecurityException usually come in multiples when they first arise...

Comment: The codebase does not solve the problem. From an admin point of view, permission java.security.AllPermission is not a solution regardless where you write it. So back to the topic why don't the commented lines solve the problem? Besides that, on our Domino 9 Server http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-8JYAT5 doesn't work

Comment: Well, those are the correct lines with regards to regular Java Security configuration, so then it must be something Domino specific. Maybe you can get some more information by starting the JVM with `java -Djava.security.debug=all`, which will print all Java Security debug output.

Comment: Putting the jackson jar in lib/ext of the JVM might also solve the problem, as it then should be loaded with the same classloader as `java.util.ArrayList` and hence shouldn't need any special permissions to access declared members.